# Links suddenly not working after working in Dreamweaver

Tags: css, html, dreamweaver

So I've created this page using Dreamweaver and it includes external links. For reasons unknown, when I viewed the page in a browser, none of the links would work. That also includes the images.

```
 <p class="paragraph">Graduating in 2008 from <a href="https://dentistry.creighton.edu/" title="Creighton University School of Dentistry" target="_blank">Creighton University School of Dentistry</a> in Nebraska, <strong>Simone Vining</strong> immediately began working for her father <strong>Simms Vining, D.D.S.</strong> at his dental practice, then named <i>The Vining Practice</i>, in Albuquerque, New Mexico.</p>
 <p class="paragraph"><strong>Aleida Saroyan</strong> graduated in 2009 from <a href="https://dental.case.edu/" title="Case Western Reserve University School of Dental Medicine" target="_blank">Case Western Reserve University School of Dental Medicine</a>. From Ohio, Saroyan attended seminars in Colorado where she met fianc&#233; <strong>Lucien Sgro</strong>, a 2005 <a href="http://www.ucdenver.edu/academics/colleges/dentalmedicine/Pages/DentalMedicine.aspx" title="University of Colorado School of Dental Medicine" target="_blank">University of Colorado School of Dental Medicine</a> graduate.
  <p class="paragraph">When <strong>Simms Vining</strong> retired after 35 years of dentistry early 2010, he gave his company to his daughter. <strong>Simone Vining</strong> decided to form a practice firm alongside her cousin, <strong>Aleida Saroyan</strong>. Along with Saroyan’s fianc&#233;, both Vining and Saroyan not only created the <em>Vining-Saroyan Dental Practice</em> for clients of all ages, but for those who are developmentally disabled in due respect to the latter having a sister born with  <a href="http://www.chargesyndrome.org/about-charge.asp" title="CHARGE Syndrome" target="_blank">CHARGE Syndrome</a>.</p>
 <p class="paragraph">Located next to <a href="https://childcare.unm.edu/" title="University of New Mexico Children’s Campus" target="_blank">University of New Mexico Children's Campus</a> on <u>3410 Camino de Salud Rd.</u> in Albuquerque, New Mexico, <em>Vining-Saroyan Dental Practice</em> offers complete dental care to patients with a wide range of services where a patients' dental health being the main priority.</p>
    <div id="maps">
        <a href="http://answersafrica.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/africa_map.png" class="map">
            <img src="http://www.yourchildlearns.com/images/africa-map.gif" width="200" alt=" map small 1"/>
        </a>
        <a href="http://www.freeworldmaps.net/russia/russia-map.gif" class="map">
            <img src="http://www.exportrussia.com/images/maps/small/map_sm_ru.gif" width="200" alt="map small 2"/>
        </a>
    </div>

#article-paragraph {
    font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: .96em;
    text-align: justify;
    padding-right: 290px;
    z-index: 500;
}

p.paragraph {
    margin: 10px 0px;

}

em {
    font-style: oblique;
}

.link  {
    color: #0000ff;
}

.link  a {
    color: #0000ff;
}

.link a:hover {
    color: #fff200;
}

.link a:visited {
    color: #ff0000;
}

a.link {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #0000FF;
}

a:hover {
    color: #fff200;
    text-decoration: none;
}

 a:visited {
    color: #FF0000;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

I also have a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/leosnake123/tb5y9bvt/2/).

Comment: the fiddle is working

Comment: What do you mean by "none of the links would work"? Do you get a hand-cursor? Is anything displayed in the browser's Console window? What about other browsers? Also, please avoid `target="_blank"`: https://marco.org/2014/01/10/target-blank

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to check the file extension you are saving as.
If the code seems to be working in JSFiddle, it has to work in DreamWeaver as well.
Try removing the target="_blank" and make it simple like this:

```
<a href="https://dentistry.creighton.edu/">Creighton University School of Dentistry</a>
```